# why downloading files from https server is not working on embedded device with montavista linux?

Tags: linux, qt, embedded

Hi I have implemented Download manager class using QNetworkAccessMnanager to download from ftp,http,https servers and its working fine on host machine (ubuntu 9.04).

but why is it not working on embedded device with montavista linux ?

here is the code link:
http://pastebin.com/ffMFXxeW

Answer (score 4):

My first guess is maybe QtNetwork is compiled without OpenSSL support, check sslErrors.